# Coordinates of a functional in dual space with one qiven coordinate.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

$f \in (\mathbb{R}^{3})^*$ is a functional of the form $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 - 3x_2 + x_3$.

$\mathcal{A} = \{α_1, α_2, α_3\}$ is a basis of the linear space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\mathcal{A}^* = \{g_1, g_2, g_3\} ⊂ (\mathbb{R}^{3})^*$ is a dual basis.

- $g_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 - x_3$
- $g_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 - 2x_2$

Assuming that the third coordinate of the functional $f$ in the basis $\mathcal{A}^∗$ is equal to $1$, find the vector $α_3$.

---

So I don't know $g_3$ but I know that "the third coordinate of the function $f$ in the basis $\mathcal{A}^∗$ is equal to $1$". I think that I need to use that information to get full $\mathcal{A}^∗$, but I'm not sure how. My first idea was to express $g_3(x_1, x_2, x_3) = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$ in matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & a & 1\\
0 & -2 & b & -3\\
-1 & 0 & c & 1
\end{bmatrix}

with an aim to get:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & ?\\
0 & 0 & 1 & ?
\end{bmatrix}

And then somehow find those $3$ variables. But that does not work for me and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the dual basis isn't just an arbitrary basis but the one *induced* by the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Your language of "*a* basis" is unusual; it should probably be "*the corresponding* basis." Once you pick a basis of $V$ you get a naturally induced basis of $V^*$.

If you do assume the $g_i$ are induced by the $\alpha_i$, then $g_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta (which is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise).

Thus $g_1(\alpha_3)=0$, $g_2(\alpha_3)=0$, and $g_3(\alpha_3)=1$.

Assume $\alpha_3=(a,b,c)$.

The first equation above tells you $a=c$, so $\alpha_3=(a,b,a)$.

The second equation tells you $a=2b$, so $\alpha_3=(2b, b, 2b)$.

Now, we also know that the third coordinate of $f$ with respect to the $g_i$ is 1, so

$$f=c_1g_1+c_2g_2+g_3$$

Thus

$$2b-3b+2b=f(\alpha_3)=c_1\underbrace{g_1(\alpha_3)}_{\text{zero}}+c_2\underbrace{g_2(\alpha_3)}_{{\text{zero}}}+\underbrace{g_3(\alpha_3)}_{\text{one}}=1$$

So $b=1$.

Thus $\alpha_3=(2,1,2)$.